# WebClient block is throwing nullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have the following code that fetches user details from another service.

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<SuccessResponse<<User>> userTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {}

User user = webClient.get()
                .uri("url")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(userTypeReference)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
                .doOnError(e -> logger.error("Error on fetching user details {}", e))
                .map(response -> response.getData())
                .block();
```

Response from the service looks like that:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
      "name": "John",
      ...
  }
}
```

If `data` element is not available, mapping returns null and on the `block()` and throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null value` error.

I know that we can handle the `nullPointerException` during the mapping and returns `new User` object if data object is null. But I don't want to get an empty object. Is there any ways to get a null value using `block()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reactive streams specification ([Subscriber, rule 13](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.3/README.md#2-subscriber-code)) forbids `null` elements, and that's exactly what your `map` operator is doing: it's returning `null` values when no user is provided in the data part of your response.

You should call `response.getData()` after the block operation, and react to `null` values there.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by Brian Clozel is well explained. I have also found another solution to this problem. We can avoid `NullPointerException` by filtering the response in this case.

```
User user = webClient.get()
                .uri("url")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(userTypeReference)
                .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
                .doOnError(e -> logger.error("Error on fetching user details {}", e))
                .filter(response -> !Objects.isNull(response.getData()))
                .map(response -> response.getData())
                .block();
```

Comment: You can use `blockOptional` as well if you want to be more explicit about the potential miss of the value.